# Is it possible to create a css class that imposes an angular filter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to create a css class that imposes an angular filter?

For example, I'd like to have a table cell display a value that will be always be right-aligned, colored cornflower blue, and formatted using an angular filter (in this case I'll pick currency).

I currently have it work with the following CSS:

```
.money {
    text-align: right;
    color: #6495ed;
}
```

And this template:

```
<td class="money">{{myContract.amountOfMoney | currency:default:0}}</td>
```

Is there a way to shorten this so both the CSS and angular filter can be applied via CSS?

Comment: Yeah just make a directive called `money` and inject the `$filter` service (and possibly the `$parse` service).  Though I would namespace the css class: `app-money`.  Or consider the class `ctf-currency-default-0` paired with the directive `classToFilter`

Comment: outside the box, you can leave the TD empty, and use a querySelector hitting the same class that css does to define the angular markup as .innerHTML in the TD, so long as that happens before angular is loaded. this is like a macro in other languages...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can create a money directive with `restrict: 'C'`.

The only trick here is to use `$timeout` to ensure that we're getting the evaluated expression with `element.text()`.

Please have a look at the demo below or at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/smx6zxn8/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myContract = {
      amountOfMoney: 100
    };
  })
  .directive('money', function(currencyFilter, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() { //timeout to ensure that the expression is evaluated
          var value = element.text();
          //console.log(currencyFilter(parseFloat(value) || 0, undefined, 0));
          element.text(currencyFilter(parseFloat(value), undefined, 0));
        }, 0);
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.money {
  text-align: right;
  color: #6495ed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <p>{{myContract.amountOfMoney | currency:default:0}}</p>
  <p class="money">{{myContract.amountOfMoney}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldnt you use scope.$apply instead of timeout so that angular can take care of it when it needs to?

Comment: `$apply` was my first try too but it creates an error `... $apply already in progress.`.